# How can I run reports from POCOs?

Tags: reporting-services, domain-driven-design, reporting, poco

I'm looking for a way to generate some nice reports from my domain model built in C#.  Using SSRS would be ideal but it's not required.

Most of our reports run directly off of our database but we have special needs for a couple of reports which require that all the data go through the domain model.  POJO reporting seems common but I haven't seen much for POCO.

Comment: I'd love to be able to report off of a RESTful web service.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS allows you to reference your own assemblies so maybe it can help you? Have a look at this article too: [Domain driven reports: adding custom code](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2009/07/08/domain-driven-reports-adding-custom-code/)

Comment: I don't see this option when I run Business Intel. Studio.  Does this require client side rendering of reports?

Comment: Not sure what option you aren't seeing in BIDS, but no, custom assemblies are executed on the SSRS server. No special client side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy answer, but you could use the [oData reflection provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728281.aspx) to turn your objects into an oData feed, then use something like [Tablaeu's oData support](http://www.tableausoftware.com/odata-data-analysis). I beliive there are some [free options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671430/odata-dynamic-reporting-tools) for reporting off of oData feeds as well.

Answer (score 0):

In code, you can add a POCO as a datasource if it is in an IEnumerable such as a simple array. Your POCO must contain only simple data types because the SSRS report doesn't support expressions like `SomeProperty.AnotherProperty.Value` So if you have a complex object, you have to flatten it into one object.

In C# :

```
public static string GetDiagramReport(MyPOCO model)
{
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport ssrsReport = new LocalReport();
    ...
    ssrsReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", new MyPOCO[] { model }));
    ...
}
```

And the SSRS designer is perfectly happy for you to add this POCO as an object datasource.

According to this question/answer you can do more complex objects if you add more code.
[Reporting Services: Business object data source with parent-child-grandchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269798/reporting-services-business-object-data-source-with-parent-child-grandchild)